# Weird slicing of threads in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

So I'm trying to print this part which has some external threads, for some reason Cura puts a lot of start/stops right on the surface of threads. And it makes the thread all dashed/choppy.

[image]

The strange part is that a very similar thread on top of the same part is printing just fine.

[image]

Is there some setting that's responsible for this? What is it trying to do with all those starts/stops?
I tried changing the thickness of the part, thinking maybe it has to do with infill pattern. This didn't help.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I didn't find a proper solution but cranking up resolution during STL export seems to make the issue go away. These start/stop points that Cura is placing have something to do with STL ridge lines